# IJCAD2018 でC#でのプログラミングにおけるaccore.dllとの互換性について

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD2018を使用してC#で開発を行っております。
AutoCADの場合、
[DllImport("accore.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int acedEntSel(String str, out AdsName objName, double[] result);
とすることでacadEntSelを呼び出すことができるようになり、
これを使用することでユーザーが選択したオブジェクトのIDや座標を取得することが
できるのですが、これはIJCAD2018では互換性のあるDLLなどは存在しないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IJCADの.NETからacadEntSel関数を使用するには、

```
[DllImport("gced.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,EntryPoint = "gcedEntSel")]
public static extern int acedEntSel(String str, out ads_name entres, double[] ptres);
```

とすることで、関数を呼び出すことが出来ると思います。